# AWS SDK configuration doesn't work on Angular application running on EC2 with instance profile role?

Tags: javascript, aws-sdk

We are have angular application running on EC2 with instance profile role.

In angular application we have use aws-sdk to fetch some details of EC2.
It is giving error "Missing credentials in config, if using AWS_CONFIG_FILE, set AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=1"

Can we configure aws-sdk without credential on EC2?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: How would an Angular application, which runs in the web browser, access the instance profile of an EC2 server?